# Search options in Elasticsearch percolate function

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-percolate

My question is how can I use search options like multimatch, slop and fuzziness in a percolate function using NEST (c#)?

I want to implement a percolate function that returns exactly the opposite result of the following search function:

```
public List<string> search(string query){
.......
.......
var searchResponse = client.Search<Document>(s => s 
                .AllTypes()
                   .From(0)
                   .Take(10)
                .Query(q => q               // define query
                    .MultiMatch(mp => mp            // of type MultiMatch
                    .Query(input.Trim())
                    .Fields(f => f          // define fields to search against
                    .Fields(f3 => f3.doc_text))
                    .Slop(2)
                    .Operator(Operator.And)
                    .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.Auto))));
}
```

The following is the percolate function I currently use but don't know how to include multimatch, slop and fuzziness options. I could not find detail about this in its documentation.

```
var searchResponseDoc = client.Search<PercolatedQuery>(s => s
               .Query(q => q
               .Percolate(f => f
               .Field(p => p.Query)
               .DocumentType<Document>() //I have a class called Document
               .Document(myDocument))) // myDocument is an object of type Document
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the first you are doing a `multi_match` query which has the options you require. In the latter you do a `percolator` query.

If you want to do both you can use binary and bitwise operators e.g

```
.Query(q => 
    !q.MultiMatch(mp => mp
        .Query(input.Trim())
        .Fields(f => f.Fields(f3 => f3.doc_text))
        .Slop(2)
        .Operator(Operator.And)
        .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.Auto)
    )
    && q.Percolate(f => f
           .Field(p => p.Query)
           .DocumentType<Document>()
           .Document(myDocument)
    )
)
```

Not the use of `&&` to create a `bool` query with the two queries as `must` clauses. The unary `!` operator negates the query by wrapping the query in a `bool` and placing the query in a `must_not` clause.

See more info https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-queries.html

and

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html

Comment: Thanks alot for your response. No I don't want to do both, I want a percolator that could consider fuzziness and slop; is that possible in Elasticsearch?